# which is better? NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary or SQL?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

My app pulls data arrays extensively from a remote server, assigns the arrays to labels, textfields and other UI components and then compare user response to the stored components.

What are the pros and cons for using NSMutableArray and SQL? Which is more efficient and memory friendly?

Comment: There is not better or worse answer in general. For your specific task there are many options and all of them have their advantages. This question is not a good fit for the SO Q/A format and will likely cause prolonged discussions, hence I voted for closing it.

Comment: This is like asking "What is better, a four door car or a two door car?"

Comment: @sosborn -- No, it's more like asking which is better, a door or a potato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NS(Mutable)Array and SQL are two entirely different things.  First off, there's little conceptual difference between an NSArray and a regular C array.  It's just that the NSArray is an Objective-C object and implements some very useful features over and above the simple C array.

Both types of arrays are linear, and elements are accessible only by index.  (Yes, NSArray supports some search functions, but they involve actual linear search internally, no different from simply coding the `do` loop yourself.)

SQL is a database facility.  It implements the ability to define database tables that are persistently stored, "associatively" accessible, and which have an internal structure of columns/cells.

You would only very rarely substitute one for the other.